# ALM installation 12.50 - "Site Admin Database Schema" Issue

Tags: oracle, windows-server-2012-r2, alm

Oracle database is connected through ALM, but when in "Site Admin Database Schema" tab, after filling in default username and default password, there is the error "The database administrator [qcsiteadmin_db] does not have all the required permissions or the schema password does not meet the password policy requirements." with the option of "Create a New Schema".

I have tried few times of password and still cannot solve it and don't have any clue on it.

Has anyone got the solution or did I miss out something?

> Windows Server 2012 R2
>
> HP ALM 12.50
>
> Oracle 12c

Answer (score 0):

```
The default password meets the password policy. So this should be a permission issue.
In the previous "Database Server" tab, did you use the DB admin user to login? If you used admin user, you can create a new connection in Oracle SQL Developer and try below queries to test the permission.

create user "<Schema_name>" IDENTIFIED by "<Schema_password>" DEFAULT TABLESPACE "<Default_Tablespace>" TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "<Temporary_Tablespace>" PROFILE DEFAULT;
GRANT CREATE VIEW TO "<Schema_name>";
GRANT CREATE TABLE TO "<Schema_name>";
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO "<Schema_name>";
GRANT CREATE TRIGGER TO "<Schema_name>";
GRANT CREATE SEQUENCE TO "<Schema_name>";
GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE TO "<Schema_name>";
```